# Which tools and technologies are used to build Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, faq-proposed, technology

Which technologies you are using for building [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)? This is interesting if it gets open sourced at some point in future. Do you use same stuff as with SO? C#, ASP.NET, MVC?

Comment: IMO this deserves to be a standalone faq now with the up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Data Explorer

Like [the rest of the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network), [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) uses a [**WISC**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177901/what-does-wisc-stack-mean) stack:

- **Operating System** [Microsoft Windows Server 2012 x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/)
- **Web Server** [IIS 8.0](http://www.iis.net/)
- **Database** [SQL Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016) running on [Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R1 x64](https://serverfault.com/questions/34846/in-place-upgrade-from-windows-server-standard-to-enterprise-or-datacenter)
- **Language** [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)

Data is populated into Data Explorer using an automated import script that converts and sanitizes data from the internal Stack Exchange databases, producing an output that is similar to the [data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/).

### Software Development Tools

- **IDE** Visual Studio 2010
- **Framework** [Microsoft ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) (version 4.0) on .NET 4.5
- **Web Framework** [ASP.NET MVC 5.2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) with [MiniProfiler](http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler)
- **View Engine** [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)
- **Browser Framework** [jQuery 1.7.1](http://jquery.com/)
- **Data Access Layer** [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) (only for [OData](http://www.odata.org/) access)
- **Source Control** [Git](http://git-scm.com/), [on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)

### External Bits

- [CodeMirror 2](http://codemirror.net/2/)
- [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)
- [Flot 0.7](http://www.flotcharts.org/)
- Stripped down version of [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)
- [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)
- [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)
- [reCAPTCHA](https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/)

Comment: do you update the db as and when database dump is released ? Or do you have, er, "some other arrangement" ;p

Comment: no arrangement yet, but I will make sure that the latest data is up in very short order after the release

Comment: @Sathya: refer to this question -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59480/provide-more-frequent-data-dumps-to-data-explorer

Comment: @Tim nice update! Where did you get all the information from? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, I know most of it, but otherwise I just copied from the network post under the assumption that it's the same.

Comment: @Brent aren't you consulting for Stack Exchange? If so, I think you should ask for a diamond here on Meta so you can edit anything at will. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard well, I've got database access, so technically I can edit anything at will anyway. I try to be good and use the UI though. ;-)

Comment: @BrentOzar cheers, so now we know who to blame when there are unexplained reputation changes! :P

Comment: I know nothing.

Answer (score 1):

While not strictly part of Data Explorer, it is possible to query Stack Overflow data as part of [BigQuery's public datasets](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow).

Comment: Also, it seems that the data available through BigQuery Public datasets program is updated from the internet archive dumps, on a quarterly fashion. As of december 2022, the latest data available via BQ is from September 2022