# Provide more frequent data dumps to Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, data-explorer

In the SO blog post "[Introducing Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/)" (2010-06-13), Jeff states in a footnote:

> we are looking at eventually making special weekly or biweekly dumps for SEDE

Is this still planned?

Comment: I'd like to get new data at SEDE more frequently too.

Answer (score 4):

This is something only the Stack Exchange team can (and should) provide a definite answer for right here, of course, but at least it is still mentioned quite prominently as the last point in the respective [FAQ](http://odata.stackexchange.com/faq), so right now we have every reason to believe that your `feature-request` is in fact `status-planned`:

> **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
>   At the moment it is updated shortly after every Stack Exchange Creative Commons Data Dump. We plan to update the data of SEDE weekly or even bi-weekly some time in the future.

Comment: Just realized the minor semantic error in the phrasing as copied verbatim, but this should really be just accidental and read as *bi-weekly or even weekly* rather than *weekly or even bi-weekly* I'd say ...

Comment: makes me wonder if by "biweekly" they actually meant "semiweekly"... very common mistake

Comment: @Kip - you are most likely right, makes much more sense like that: interestingly the dictionary I usually refer to initially (being a non native speaker myself) actually provides translations with both meanings for [bi-weekly](http://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&search=bi-weekly), while [semiweekly](http://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&search=semiweekly) seems unambiguous, so the former ambiguity appears to be kind of an already 'accepted' public change of meaning?!

Comment: Unfortunately, the faq has been changed to "How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated? --
Data is updated monthly.", so this has become more of a `status-declined` :(