# Are the data queries cached on Data Explorer? Why doesn't my recent activity show up?

Tags: support, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Data from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer are obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete)

I've been running this query for the past few days but every time I get the same count. I've edited a few posts every day, so I know that count should change. What am I missing?

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges?UserId=244353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq):

> ### How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
>
> Data is updated monthly.

I would imagine that the resources required to run such queries off the live database would be insanely prohibitive, and if it's going to be periodic snapshots a month is as good an interval as any.

Keep in mind that they may actually want to *discourage* people running expensive queries on their own statistics on a regular basis. I vaguely recall hearing that viewing vote counts has such a high rep requirement largely because they didn't want people hammering the DB server with it.

Comment: _monthly_ is bit too much. But anyway, thanks for answer!

Comment: @Mrchief: You mean monthly isn't quite often enough? That's been discussed before, see [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59480/provide-more-frequent-data-dumps-to-data-explorer), for example. Although it looks like the hint towards more frequent dumps in the future has been removed for good...

Comment: Not for me atleast. A month in today's times seems like eternity!