# Data Explorer - is an update overdue?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

I know the Data Explorer is a privilege and not a right, but I thought it was now done monthly - the last update was Oct 4th.

Can we get some fresh data to play with please?!

Comment: Particularly pertinent given queries like: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2042/users-eligible-for-2011-stack-overflow-moderator-elections

Comment: The [Data Explorer FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq) does read: **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
_Data is updated monthly._ but it doesn't look like the automatic weekly or bi-weekly updates are [tag:status-planned] as [they once were](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59480/146495).

Comment: I've accepted my own answer below but can't add the `Status-Completed` tag as I'm not a mod. Could someone who is do the honours please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data explorer now appears to have been updated as of Nov 13th.