# Data Explorer — are updates still happening?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I occasionally browse the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and appreciate it's not real-time, but only a snapshot at the time it was last updated.

I thought it was updated monthly, at least that's what the FAQ states but there's been no update since the end of June.

I asked a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111366/data-explorer-is-an-update-overdue) previously and it was updated.

So, are monthy updates unofficial (in which case I'll stop asking every time it's "overdue") or is this a bug/oversight?

Comment: More updated answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/197639)

Answer (score 6):

In general, the update schedule is supposed to be somewhere between monthly and bi-monthly. Since it requires some level of manual involvement by a developer though, sometimes Data Explorer updates have to take a back seat to more pressing changes.

However, there are some additional potential delay factors at the moment. The most relevant of these is the fact that Data Explorer may be moving house as part of [hardware upgrades to the network](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/08/16/the-move-to-sql-2012/). Once the dust has settled on that whole process, I'm hoping that it will be easier to update Data Explorer on a more consistent basis (though I don't know specifically how the process works or what plans are in place, so don't hold me to that).

Comment: Is Data Explorer still based on the Data Dump?  I'll remove my answer if it's not.

Comment: It has its own internal export/import process that doesn't require the Data Dump, or so I've been told.

Comment: Any updates on this? It has been months.

Comment: This is ridiculous. It's more than **half a year now** without updates. If the team decided to kill data explorer it's OK but please make it official and announce.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, the data itself (which this question is about) is quite up to date. The *code* is a separate story, but as I'm not an employee I have little control over that. There's every intention of updating the code, but it is unfortunately low priority.