# Query limit on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

How do I use ROWCOUNT and TOP to limit the query results on [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE)?

For example, fetch me 10 posts tagged JavaScript which have fiddles in them.

Reason - Timeout expired

Comment: are you asking how to write the TSQL to get those answers, or are you asking us to help you debug a particular bit of TSQL in respect to [data.se] to ensure that you're doing the right thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure how on topic this is but I understand how the timeout's on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer can be annoying. [Apparently, a new server is in the offing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/179419), which *might* makes things better.

You're probably looking for [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx), a T-SQL function, which:

> Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in
> a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not found, on all
> valid text and character data types.

For instance

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 *
  FROM posts
 WHERE PATINDEX('%http://jsfiddle.net%', body) <> 0
   and tags like '%javascript%'
```

[As demonstrated here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/78804/free-text-lookup?).

The other option is [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323); apparently (I have no idea) there's [not much difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372583/how-about-the-performance-between-patindex-and-charindex).