# What tags generate the most reputation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, data-explorer

Is there a way to find the tags that generate the most reputation?

What is the average reputation generation per question (total reputation generated to the original poster and to the answers) for each tag?

*Edit:* Thanks for introducing Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Comment: Perhaps you can create your own query using the date explorer? http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bart Is it still wroking? That db didn't show my details when i tried it few weeks back. I thought the db wasn't updated since ages

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Sure that still works. The data is somewhat outdated at the moment, but if it's an overview you want, it should still work just fine.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Have a look at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145697/187824)

Comment: Great! So it'll be updated on weekly basis soon . Good to see that :)

Comment: @Bart Cool! But running it for all tags takes too long and the query is timed-out.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect that to happen. Perhaps limit it to the top most popular tags instead.

Comment: Starting with a process of elimination... Its NOT the facebook tag ;-)

Comment: @Lix :) it has 1.0088212377560106 avg reputation per question

Answer (score 6):

[These](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82274/what-tag-generates-most-reputation?UserId=986743) are tags with more than 25000 posts, the number is the average score per post:

```
TagName                Reputation
-----------------------------------------
"language-agnostic"    "5.27807351875768"
"git"                  "4.10926245021327"
"perl"                 "3.03355357427161"
"r"                    "2.93912202668729"
"delphi"               "2.85040211611938"
"math"                 "2.67766788902471"
"generics"             "2.67338523200247"
"optimization"         "2.62554770457506"
"string"               "2.5914080963635"
"c"                    "2.54512436480342"
"list"                 "2.53335211443954"
"python"               "2.52299378731032"
"c++"                  "2.52011010816699"
"performance"          "2.48604146162378"
"cocoa"                "2.45970735968552"
"svn"                  "2.45222290580578"
"algorithm"            "2.42602165667442"
"cocoa-touch"          "2.38567812697743"
"oop"                  "2.3603381241536"
```

`facebook` is the least reputation producing tag with `1.0088212377560106`

Comment: @null - actually that's quite logical to me. The popular tags probably have much *more answers per post* dragging down the average. A great +5 score answer just gets watered down by 6 other identical one liners...

Comment: @zenpoy: What do you mean by posts? questions+answers?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ They're not missing: `c# : 2.01188649642285
java : 1.88243548207646
php : 1.38446562166671`

Comment: @zenpoy You're right; it's just Chrome's Find feature being stupid

Comment: 15 significant digits are not warranted. They ought to be round to 2 or 3 significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

zenpoy's answer is great, except that I'm more fascinated by the less popular tags.  Running his query with a threshold of 2000 gives these as the top results:

```
tips-and-tricks             10.0542
polls                       8.37928
code-golf                   6.74098
rosetta-stone               6.08658
language-agnostic           5.27807
operators                   5.27608
dvcs                        5.10741
language-features           5.06719
haskell                     5.03437
functional-programming      4.89002
printf                      4.30735
branch                      4.29337
big-o                       4.26206
scala                       4.24377
mathematica                 4.22935
clojure                     4.2074
language-design             4.18894
interview-questions         4.16682
c++11                       4.15281
puzzle                      4.13688
git                         4.10926
productivity                4.09837
ocaml                       4.09282
programming-languages       4.05066
lisp                        4.00952
guid                        3.93861
teaching                    3.91215
vim                         3.89149
tuples                      3.82788
theory                      3.78526
self-improvement            3.77712
complexity                  3.77483
computer-science            3.77002
books                       3.76922
pythonic                    3.75993
c++0x                       3.69485
f#                          3.63583
terminology                 3.61984
immutable                   3.54214
boolean                     3.54189
syntax                      3.5192
coding-style                3.47707
version-control             3.44991
common-lisp                 3.44671
history                     3.42139
mercurial                   3.39731
ggplot2                     3.39627
extension-methods           3.3906
enums                       3.37566
const                       3.32906
floating-point              3.31076
text-editor                 3.29644
bit-manipulation            3.28041
resharper                   3.25669
closures                    3.24786
go                          3.24516
ienumerable                 3.22445
constants                   3.19331
stl                         3.18832
```

Comment: I see a few there that should be torched...

Comment: @Lix a number are from an earlier era when questions were more open.