# Why is data.stackoverflow.com four months out of date?

Tags: bug, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will data.SE get updated data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data)

The data.* sites all appear to be four months out of date. This is effectively useless for up to date stats. Is there a reason it is so far out of date? The FAQ states that it is updated every month. Am I missing something?