# Is there any way to get access to user statistics?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

I am curious about some of the reputation and badging statistics that exist in the StackExchange universe.

In particular, things like:

- Total reputation points
- Total number of questions
- Total number of answers
- Badge information (at least total number of each badge colour)

Anonymized would be fine; is this available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have access to the data! Check [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Compose your own query and select the data you want. Currently the data will be [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data).

Answer (score -1):

all that stuff is in the profile page of a member's profile

reputation and badge details are in the right column, where questions and answers are in the left column.

you can click on the bold headings to expand details too.