# Query Stack Overflow: Not showing original reputation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer

I just checked out top users in my country, and I saw I am also there. But the case is, it is not showing my original reputation! It is showing 1674 while I have more than 1800. Why is this??

Comment: Is this the data explorer? The data it uses is only updated every week or so.

Comment: Where are you getting a readout of top users by country?

Comment: @ChrisF If that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was going to say month but I thought the refresh rate had been increased.

Comment: It should be about weekly now. We lagged behind a bit while moving datacenters, but I think we're back on track now.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks for the comment.  But what is the date they do updates? Sunday? Monday?

Comment: @Yohan Sunday. You can see how recent the data is on each site by checking the date in each row in the site list on Data SE.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks :) Does that mean these sites are not linked?

Comment: @AnnaLear: Where is Data SE?

Comment: @Yohan http://data.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) does not contain live data. It gets [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data).

Comment: OK Thanks. But what is the date they do updates? Sunday? Monday?