# Getting detailed user statistics

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm trying to get some more robust user information (on myself, specifically) across stack exchange sites.  The User tab isn't enough.  I need things like how many answers have I posted since October 1 of last year?  How many of those answers were accepted?  What badges did I receive in that period?

I've been searching for an hour now, but I'm surprised that I'm not finding any application that helps out with this.  Yes, I realize that there's an API that I can use to mine this information but that looks like a fair bit of work, considering I'm not really a web developer and OAuth from a desktop app looks like a whole lotta not fun.

Ideally, each specific exchange site would give me the capability to mine this information, but unless I'm missing something, they do not.  Before I dive into this, am I missing some tool or app that already has done this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done easily through the API without OAuth. For instance, [your posts since October 1st, 2012 on SO](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users#page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=2012-10-01&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=13154&filter=!9ciXfDSYM&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (you have 121).

[Your badges from October 1st, 2012 on SO](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-on-users#page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=2012-10-01&order=desc&sort=rank&ids=13154&filter=!9ciXfDSYM&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (you have 16).

<sup>You can use the first query on questions to see what % have `is_accepted` as true, but that requires looping through the results checking the `has_more` property to see if it is true -- this isn't overly complex, and shouldn't require any magical feat of strength if you are a developer of any sort. Point is, the API can do this all easily</sup>

Answer (score 8):

With a little SQL knowledge you can query such data from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). It is [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data).

Browse existing queries. There may be queries for some of your questions.