# Sort users by joining date?

Tags: support, user-list

Is there a way to sort the users by their joining date? So that I can see who is the oldest user and also who is the latest user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go using [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854152/top-x-oldest-users?Top=100)

```
SELECT TOP ##Top## ID AS [User Link], Reputation
              , CreationDate, LastAccessDate, Location
  FROM Users
 ORDER BY CreationDate
```

For the latest users just order the records in [descending order](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854156/top-x-newest-users?Top=100) instead of ascending order.

```
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

Note that data in Data.SE is [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/187824) So the latest users will be at least one week old. However it won't affect the oldest users :)

Comment: Nice! And here is the same query just [in descending order](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/124567/top-100-oldest-users?Top=100) - note the data will be up to week old.

Comment: For some reason I dont see any result. Its just blank.

Comment: @Rishav: Not sure how the queries were changed. Anyway, I have updated both queries. You can check now. :)

Comment: @hims056 Yea that works now. Thanks. I wonder why one of the co-founders cum member is not on the top?

Comment: @Rishav: [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) *is* co-founder of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, such feature is not available for normal users. May be [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/) help you to finding users by joining date.

Each user has given a unique user Id, based on this Id you can differentiate between two or more users that which user has joined site first.