# How to search if I ever answered any question of a particular user before, by user name?

Tags: support, search

I want to check if I have ever answered any questions asked by a particular user, by the user name. Is there a search syntax for this?

Comment: no, but there is a query that might help http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/108025/where-did-we-meet

Comment: Remember we can't search anything by username(i.e. display-name) except [users](http://stackoverflow.com/users) and [leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow). We have to use user's ID to search.

Comment: People change their display names a lot.

Comment: @hjpotter92, user id would work too.

Comment: @juergend, feel free to post your comment as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: You can use `user:<id>` in the search box in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no search pattern that would return your desired results.

But you could use a [query from the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/108025/where-did-we-meet) to get post where you ran into a specific user.

But keep in mind that the Data Explorer is not up-to-date. [It is updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/).