# How do I view my post views on all Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, support

I just want to check the views of my questions on all Stack Exchange sites. Where to check this?

Comment: There's unlikely to be a feature that shows this, as it's a fairly esoteric request. If view data is not included in the Data Dump (and I doubt it is, and it would be difficult to get it from there even then), you may have to count and add them manually

Comment: Loved the `fairly esoteric request` but I think it's pretty mundane and perfectly valid desire. Don't have any code at hand, but I think it'd be a simple API request looping through `/user/accounts` -> `/questions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can be satisfied with a weekly update the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/534147?accountid=2142001) gives you the viewcount for all your questions:

```sql
declare @accountid int = ##accountid:int?2142001##

-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                       , postid int
                       , title nvarchar(250)
                       , viewcount int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , p.id
     , p.title
     , p.viewcount
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts p
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where u.accountid = ' + cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + '
and posttypeid = 1 -- Q
'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

--print @sql

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results
select site
      , 
       -- URL builder from Lamak http://stackoverflow.com/a/38129701
      'http://' 
      + case PARSENAME(site,1)
        when 'audio' then 'avp'
        else PARSENAME(site,1)
        end 
      + coalesce('.' 
        + case PARSENAME(site,2)
          when 'audio' then 'avp'
          else PARSENAME(site,2)
          end , '')
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , ''
      , coalesce('.' + PARSENAME(site,3), '')
      )
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , '.net'
      , '.com'
      ) 
      + '/q/'
      + cast(postid as nvarchar)
      + '|'
      + title
      -- rest of columns
      , viewcount
from #results
order by viewcount desc

drop table #results
```

When run today your results look like:

[image: viewcount questions of user networkwide]

Keep in mind SEDE is only [updated once a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/152859).