# Unable to find my name in Users by Country query

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, location

I'm just finding my name in the below query which sent by my friend :)

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/53058/top-users-by-country

I just entered **India.**

However surprisingly my name is not there.

Here is my stack profile :

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927832/ss

Though it's not a thing to worry, but still have a pin in my mind.

Can anyone tell the reason ? or am I missing some thing ?

Comment: When did you edit your profile and added your location? The Data Explorer data is not live and updated only once a week.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, 2 days back. That might be the reason. One week is a big span of updation :(

Comment: Maybe that's a hidden message from your government, you're not Indian anymore.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Thanks to devs that they are updating weekly now. Before it was updating monthly..

Comment: @hims056 My god. One month ??? Thanks to Data Explorer team for quick updations.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes. I'm still an Indian. Hope you won't ask my passport number here :-D

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ the whole Data Explorer is just a bonus, it's not official part of Stack Exchange. So we should thank the team for letting it exist and updating the data weekly. :)

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the comments by [hims056](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/187824/hims056) and [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) but here is the [official FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq):

> How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
> The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Jun 15 at 5:38.

You are listed in place 23 in the dump from June, 15 th 2014. I provide the evidence here and used a freehand red circle to highlight the fact. Congratulation with your current position, keep it up!

[image]

For extra background to explain the tone of some comments (just joking) this is worth reading: [When will data.SE get updated data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data/145732#145732)