# Search query - Find all users who answered questions tagged x or y or z

Tags: discussion, support, users, search

How I can list all users who answered questions tagged x and/or y and/or z.

Example how I can find:

Top 100 users who answered questions tagged [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) and/or [eclipse-rcp](/questions/tagged/eclipse-rcp)

Comment: You mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse/topusers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the top 30 users of a tag pretty easy. Go to the tag page and click [*top users*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse/topusers).

For more you could create a SQL query returning your desired results in the [*Stack Exchange Data Explorer*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

<sub>* Currently the data will be [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data).</sub>