# Searching for community wiki answers with multiple editors

Tags: support, search, community-wiki

I can search for community wiki answers by using `wiki:yes is:answer`.

Is there any way I can restrict that selection to only include those answers that have been edited by multiple people and where the reputation of the last editor is less than 2000?

As wiki edits can be made by low rep users (100+) without approval, they tend to go unnoticed, and I would like to manually review post under the above criteria (maybe to conclude that this is wasted time as harm is never or seldom done).

With the list result from searching `wiki:yes is:answer` I have to open the actual link to the post to see if there is more than one editor, and then once more to get the edit history and see who the last editor was (which fortunately also show the reputation of that editor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with the search functions on the site. You have to fallback to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I've created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/534107) that lists all posts that match the criteria you requested:

```sql
select p.id  as [Post Link]
     , case 
       when posttypeid = 1 then 'Q'
       when posttypeid = 2 then 'A'
       when posttypeid in (4,5) then 'tag'
       else cast(posttypeid as nvarchar)
       end
     , ph.userid as [User Link]
     , u.reputation
     , ph.creationdate
from posts p
inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
inner join users u on ph.userid = u.id
where communityowneddate is not null  -- is CW
and ph.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6)   -- edits (body, tag, title)
and u.reputation < 2000               -- user reputation
and ph.userid > -1 -- no community please
-- is last edit also from this user
and ph.id = (select max(phm.id) 
             from posthistory phm
             where phm.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6)
             and phm.postid = ph.postid)
-- are there multiple editors             
and exists (select 1 
            from posthistory phm
            where phm.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6)
            and phm.postid = ph.postid
            group by phm.userid
            having count(*)>1)
order by ph.creationdate desc
```

The query joins the posts and posthistory tables because the latter holds the events for edits to a post (types 4, 5 and 6). Checking the last event against the user rep is trivial.

When run today the result looks like:

[image: wiki posts that have been edited by < 2000 rep users]

Keep in mind SEDE is only [updated once a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/152859).

Meta is also a good place to run this query on:

[image: Meta query]

(There aren't any more sites that largely use the Community Wiki feature other than those two)

Comment: This already looks good, but also lists community wikis that have been edited by one person multiple times. (e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39281050/revisions) one). Once you click the post it is easy to see how many different editors there are, but it would be nice have that info up front, as I am mainly interested in low rep users editing other peoples wikis

Comment: @Anthon fixed in the current version of the query

Comment: @rene I went ahead and made https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1147/searching-for-community-wiki-answers-with-multiple-editors but I can't remember how to invite (I probably don't have enough rep on Meta)