# How to find reputation for a particular tag

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, data-explorer

How is tag-wise reputation calculated and displayed?

Example: For the SQL Server tag we can find out total reputation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/topusers

[image: Screenshot of top users]

I tried the same in https://data.stackexchange.com with the below query, but it pulls the wrong result:

```
SELECT owneruserid,
       Sum(score * 10) AS post_repuation
FROM   posts
WHERE  owneruserid = 3349551
       AND posttypeid = 1
       AND tags LIKE '%sql%server%'
GROUP  BY owneruserid
```

Link for query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/540726

Comment: @Cai it always shows yourself at the end, if you have rep in that tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the top answers, but you're querying the questions. Also as you are only looking at score, you don't have to calculate reputation. If you need that you have to join the votes table and sum indeed up and down votes.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/540739/how-to-find-reputation-for-a-particular-tag?UserId=3349551) is better I think:

```
select p.OwnerUserId as [User Link] -- is you
     , sum(p.score) as post_repuation  -- answer score
from posts p  -- answers
inner join posts q on q.id = p.parentid -- link answer to question
where p.OwnerUserId = 3349551  -- 
and p.posttypeid = 2 -- answers
and q.tags like '%<sql-server>%' -- tags are enclosed in brackets
                                 -- and are only filled for questions
group by p.OwnerUserId
```

When run today it shows a score of 1898. Keep in mind that SEDE is only [updated once a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/152859).

Comment: Ha thank you... silly me