# SEDE Query - How many days with more than specific reputation?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Is there a query to check how many days I have earned a specific reputation (say 100)?

I have checked this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90194/how-many-days-with-more-than-200-reputation), but it returns only the user.

Comment: You can't get that exactly from SEDE because your own down votes can not be accounted for.

Comment: @rene ok thanks, but is there a way to check even though its not 100% accurate?

Comment: Yeah, let me find one of mine you can use as a start. Try [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/204782/top-users-by-reputation-with-rep-cap-and-member-for-days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/557284?rep=100&UserId=1749403) gives the rough idea. Keep in mind that I didn't take the reputation cap into account. Also the rep you lost due to down voting answers is not accounted for as that data is not in SEDE.

```sql
declare @userid int = ##userid?1749403##
declare @rep int = ##rep?100##
;with
voting as (
         SELECT 
                SUM(case votes.votetypeid 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 15  -- accept
                        WHEN 2 THEN   -- upvote
                           CASE posts.posttypeid 
                              WHEN 1 THEN 5  -- upvote question
                              WHEN 2 THEN 10  -- upvote answer
                           END
                        WHEN 3 THEN -2  -- downvote
                        WHEN 9 THEN BountyAmount -- collected bounty
                 END) as Rep,
                 Votes.CreationDate AS CreationDate
          FROM   Posts
          INNER JOIN Votes              
                   ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id
          WHERE (Posts.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL 
                 or votes.creationdate < Posts.CommunityOwnedDate )
          and owneruserid = @userid
           
          GROUP BY Votes.CreationDate
),
bounty as (
         SELECT 
                SUM(-BountyAmount) as Rep,  -- Bounty given
                Votes.CreationDate AS CreationDate
          FROM  Votes                    
          WHERE votes.votetypeid = 8
          and userid = @userid
          GROUP BY Votes.CreationDate
),
sugedit as (  -- suggested edits
          SELECT 
                 COUNT(*) * 2 as Rep 
               , cast(ApprovalDate as date) As CreationDate
          FROM  SuggestedEdits 
          WHERE ApprovalDate IS NOT NULL
          and owneruserid = @userid
          GROUP BY cast(ApprovalDate as date)
)

select count(*) as days_above
     , @rep as reputation
from
(
select creationdate
     , sum(coalesce(voting,0)) as voting
     , sum(coalesce(bounties,0)) as bounties
     , sum(coalesce(sugedits,0)) as sugedits
     , sum(coalesce(voting,0)) + sum(coalesce(bounties,0)) + sum(coalesce(sugedits,0)) as tot
from 
(
select creationdate
     , rep as voting
     , 0 as bounties
     , 0 as sugedits
from voting
union
select creationdate
     , 0 
     , rep
     , 0
from bounty
union
select creationdate
     , 0 
     , 0
     , rep
from sugedit
) alldata
group by creationdate
having sum(coalesce(voting,0)) + sum(coalesce(bounties,0)) + sum(coalesce(sugedits,0)) > @rep
) perdates
```

When I run this today the outcome is:

```
+--------------------------+
| days_above  | reputation |
+-------------+------------+
|  29         |   100      |
+--------------------------+
```

Keep in mind SEDE is only [updated once a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/152859).