# How can I view my most recent questions across SE?

Tags: support, search, newest-questions

I want to review my most recent questions and answers across the Stack Exchange network.

I can view my newest questions for a specific site by [appending `?tab=questions&sort=newest`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions&sort=newest) to my user profile, but this [isn't an option on my Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/current?tab=questions&sort=newest).

I'm not able to use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for this, as the database is [updated weekly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/351462).

**Is there any way to view my most recent questions across Stack Exchange?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get the questions alone.

But from the first line of your question

> I want to review my most recent questions and answers across the Stack Exchange network.

You can go for this

Go to Stack Exchange main site, click on your name at top, choose activity and navigate to posts tab.

[image]

Or use this direct link

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/{userid}?page=1&filter=posts
```

<sup>*Note that this direct link is not supposed to view directly. It is supposed to render in the activity page and this direct link won't have any styles*</sup>

Comment: As far as I can tell, the closest that gets is "posts", which isn't "questions" as it includes questions and answers.

Comment: It looks like [`https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity`](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) works as a direct link for any logged in user.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro yes the initial version contained that link but it points to all activities including review,comment, etc